# firebase database connection error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone know whether there is a way to properly check for errors in the initial connection with the Firebase database? This is my example code

```
const database = firebase
  .initializeApp({ databaseURL: FIREBASE_URL })
  .database();
```

and in order to test that my error handling was correct I tried deleting a character from the URL, but this just prints the following to the console:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (FIREBASE_URL)

I looked thoroughly through the documentation, the most relevant page I could find is [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database), but even trying to use the `enableLogging` method and trying to regex whether it's a warning / error seems too flimsy because the above warning isn't even part of that logging.

If there was even just an attribute I could access to check whether the database is online that'd be great, or at best an error callback or something of the like.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: here `FIREBASE_URL` you need to put your firebase url. that seems like a constant

Comment: Yes I understand that but sorry if I wasn't clear, I'll remove the quotes to improve clarity

Comment: is this issue still present??

Comment: @Kenry Sanchez Has Firebase published a new update since last week? Because otherwise yes, this issue isn't about me not being able to get Firebase working, I have it working, it's about not being able to add proper error handling to my firebase initialization.